# Couldn't submit reactive form in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

I am learning Angular, I am stuck at trying to submit a form.

This is my addPost component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-addpost',
  templateUrl: './addpost.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addpost.component.css']
})
export class AddpostComponent implements OnInit {
  createPostForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder : FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createPostForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['' , Validators.required],
      content: ['' , Validators.required]
    });
  }

  createPost(){
    alert()
  }

}
```

This is my addPost html

```
<div class="container mt-2">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>Add Post</h2>
          <form [formGroup]="createPostForm" (ngSumbit)="createPost()" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Title</label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="title" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="content">Content</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="content" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Post">
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what I'm missing here, it's just a simple reactive form...

Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: ``(ngSubmit)='createPost(createPostForm.value)'`` should give you the value in your function .

Answer (score 1):

There is typo error in your code

change

```
(ngSumbit)="createPost()"
```

to

```
(ngSubmit)="createPost()"
```

Comment: thanks i was tired of searching google, you saved me. So stupid of me

Comment: np, sometime it happens.